# Can you create item list from active record and use it as a dependency for task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake

Can you create a set of items using active record that serves as a dependency for a task?

What I'm getting at is something like this is example from [this post](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2014/04/22/rake-part-2-file-lists/) by Avid Grimm, except that the `source_files` variable (or an equivalent) would be populated instead by an Active Record query on a model in a Rails app:

```
source_files = Rake::FileList.new("**/*.md", "**/*.markdown") do |fl|
  fl.exclude("~*")
  fl.exclude(/^scratch\//)
  fl.exclude do |f|
    `git ls-files #{f}`.empty?
  end
end

task :default => :html
task :html => source_files.ext(".html")

rule ".html" => ".md" do |t|
  sh "pandoc -o #{t.name} #{t.source}"
end

rule ".html" => ".markdown" do |t|
  sh "pandoc -o #{t.name} #{t.source}"
end
```

So what I'm thinking of would be something like this:

```
items = App::SomeModel.where(...)

task :some_task => items

rule /<some-regex-pattern>/ do |t|
  # does some based on each item in items
end
```

This seems possible, and seems as though it would appropriately take advantage of Rake's logic, but the barrier I am hitting is that I don't see a good way of populating the `item` list. I can't seem to call Active Record models in the context of rake task except by using the `:environment` dependency for a task, but I don't think I can't populate `items` with a task...

Does anyone know how to go about this? Or is there another better, more idiomatic, way to go about this?